# How come I can't use explicit constructor for constructing a return type

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

I played around with explicit constructors and their behavior, so I created this class:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    explicit X(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor\n";
    }
    explicit X(X const& x)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
    }
    explicit X(X&& x)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor\n";
    }
};
```

Which is basically just a stub to to test explicit constructors.
Then I wanted to try several situations. So I tried this:

```
X foo(void)
{
    X a{};
    return a;  // ERROR: no matching constructor found!
}

int main()
{
    X w{};  // Default Constructor
    X x{w};  // Copy Constructor
    X y{std::move(x)};  // Move Constructor
    X z{foo()};
}
```

And as you can see I can't return `a` inside `foo()`. I know it tries to initialize the return type `Foo` with the copy constructor, but for some reason it can't use it.

How come it can't use my provided copy constructor? I know that the `explicit` specification causes the problem, because when I remove it from the copy constructor it works. But why?

What confuses me even more is that I can do the following:

```
void bar(const X& a) { /* */ }
bar(X{});
```

It doesn't complain. But shouldn't `bar()` construct it's parameter `a` the same way `foo()` constructs its return type?

Comment: calling `bar` doesn't call constructor at all, it just pass reference (pointer). you should see the no copy constructors are called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are returning from `foo`:

```
X foo()
{
    X a{};
    return a;
}
```

You are implicitly copying `a` into the return of `foo`. But the copy constructor is marked `explicit`, so that is disallowed.

I'm not sure there is ever a reason to mark the copy/move constructors `explicit`.

Comment: But I still can use define `void bar(const X& a)` and use it like this `bar(X{});`. Isn't this an implicit copy as well?

Comment: @henrikgiesel Nope. `a` is a reference, which you're just binding to the temporary `X{}`.

Comment: Okay, I finally got the picture when I rewrote `X& foo()` and it worked. (Of course that's stupid, but it helped me understand what was going on)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood the meaning of `explicit`. An `explicit` constructor WILL NOT BE USED FOR IMPLICIT TYPE CONVERSIONS/CASTS. This means the

```
X foo(void){
    X a{};
    return a;  // ERROR: no matching constructor found!
}
```

won't compile since you've already told the compiler not to use the copy constructor implicitly.

I reckon that what you want to achieve is "move" rather than copy `a`. As long as there is a (normal) move constructor in your class, `a` will be moved rather than copied anyway - this is the default behaviour. Actually, even with c++99, most compilers are clever enough to optimise out this copy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you said you didn't want the compiler to use it implicitly when you declared it explicit.

```
explicit X(X const& x)
```

But `x` has to be copied into the return value. Just change it to

```
X(X const& x)
```

and everything will work.

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bcf453fbe609ea3)</kbd>**

Comment: *"I know that the explicit specification causes the problem, because when I remove it from the copy constructor it works. But why?"* - OP.

Comment: That means, there is no way in hell I can make `foo()` return an intact `Foo` object?

Comment: Not that I know of, but why would anyone want to declare the copy constructor explicit? What is the intended gain?