# Why adding `explicit` to a defaulted copy constructor prevents returning an object?

Tags: c++, c++17, default-constructor, explicit

Considering this [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (the real case involves some class with some inheritance and some member variables)

```
class A {
    public:
    
    A() = default;
    explicit A(const A&) = default;
    // explicit A(A&) = default; ///Adding this serves no purpose
    explicit A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
};

auto dummy_a() {
    A a;
    return a; //no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)'
}

int main() {
    const auto a = dummy_a();
}
```

I get the following error unless I remove `explicit` from either the copy or the move constructor. (Can be tested [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d727b9e633a1b6a7))

```
main.cpp: In function 'auto dummy_a()':
main.cpp:14:12: error: no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)'
   14 |     return a; //no matching function for call to 'A::A(A)'
      |            ^
main.cpp:4:5: note: candidate: 'constexpr A::A()'
    4 |     A() = default;
      |     ^
main.cpp:4:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: By making the copy and move constructor explicit, you make it impossible for the compiler to user either to return `a` without you first explicitly asking for it. `return A{a};` should work instead.

Comment: is the "non const" actually relevant? Its the same error whith `const A a; return a;`, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are right, removed `const` from the text of my question

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688633/how-come-i-cant-use-explicit-constructor-for-constructing-a-return-type) and [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480545/explicit-copy-constructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `dummy_a` your return value requires implicit copy construction

```
auto dummy_a() {
    A a;
    return a; // implicit 'A::A(A)'
}
```

If you indeed want your copy constructor to be `explicit` then this should be modified to

```
auto dummy_a() {
    A a;
    return A{a}; // explicit 'A::A(A)'
}
```